# How to calculate NTLM hash in python?

Tags: python, hash, ntlm

How can I calculate NTLM hash of a passowrd in python? Is there any library or sample code?

I want it for writing a NTLM brute force tools with python (Like Cain & Abel )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is actually very quite simple use `hashlib` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html)

```
import hashlib,binascii
hash = hashlib.new('md4', "password".encode('utf-16le')).digest()
print binascii.hexlify(hash)
```

Or you can additionally use the `python-ntlm` library [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/)

Comment: A slightly more simpler form -  


`import hashlib

print(hashlib.new('md4', "password".encode('utf-16le')).hexdigest())`

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of the hashlib and binascii modules to compute your NTLM hash:

```
import binascii, hashlib
input_str = "SOMETHING_AS_INPUT_TO_HASH"
ntlm_hash = binascii.hexlify(hashlib.new('md4', input_str.encode('utf-16le')).digest())
print ntlm_hash
```

Comment: why not this? 
http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.nthash.html  not familiar with NTLM hash at already.

Comment: `passlib` is a separate python package, but `binascii` and `hashlib` are part of the standard python library. Not saying you should not use `passlib`, it is upto the author's preference. There are other libraries as well like [`python-ntlm`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ntlm).

Comment: Thanks. interesting how OP checked the other guy. He just copy and paste from an online source code and you being the first one didn't get checked.